# Google sites api "real" html?

Tags: python, google-sites

How can I retrieve content from Google Sites using the API and display this content as "real" html without their namespace?

The html that is returned looks like:

```
<html:div>div content, nested html</html:div>
```

browsers do not recognize this namespace and renders the output as text. I access their API using python

Comment: hm - had hoped for something easier.